# Encoding without a String in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, encode, garbage

In the following method, how it is possible to return the Cp037 byte[] without creating a String object... maybe using some encode() methods and Charset?

```
  public byte[] encodeCp037(byte[] bytes)
  {
    String str = null;
    try
    {
      str = new String(bytes, "Cp037");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid encoding. Charset=Cp037.");
    }

    return str.getBytes();
  }
```

Comment: You could probably work with StreamReaders and StreamWriters. But what's wrong with the `String`?

Comment: I'm wondering why is **garbage** tag useful for this question?

Comment: You really asking if it's possible to do a character encoding without encoding characters? What do you think a `String` is?

Comment: The code is transform a Cp037 byte[] into a "platform default Charset" byte[]. Is this really your purpose?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose... I don't want the String as I do not wanna create any garbage... maybe it's not possible

Comment: Are you sure you want the platform default encoding? And, in general but especially in that case, wouldn't streaming it to its destination be the next step, which could likely be done in the same step?

Answer (score 0):

This method can change encoding without creating a `String`.(Of course it has overhead but no `String`)

```
public static byte[] transform(byte[] bytes, String fromCharset, String toCharset) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    CharBuffer charBuffer = Charset.forName(fromCharset).decode(byteBuffer);
    ByteBuffer targetBuffer = Charset.forName(toCharset).encode(charBuffer);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(targetBuffer.array(), targetBuffer.position(), targetBuffer.limit());
}
```

And you can use it convert from cp037 to utf-8 for example.

```
byte[] cp037 = "123".getBytes("cp037");
byte[] utf8 = transform(cp037, "cp037", "utf8");
System.out.println(new String(utf8, "utf-8"));
```

This will print `123` and it was converted successfully.

Comment: `ByteBuffer` uses `byte[]` to store data, meanwhile `CharBuffer` uses `char[]`. So this code uses same memory as the `String` version, since `String` uses `char[]` too.

Comment: When you use `targetBuffer.array()` on a `ByteBuffer` you didn’t create yourself, you should also respect [`targetBuffer.arrayOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#arrayOffset--). In fact, you should be prepared for the possibility that `encode` returns a buffer which hasn’t an array at all, i.e. is a direct buffer. The alternative is to acquire a `CharsetEncoder` and [pass your own `ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-java.nio.ByteBuffer-boolean-)…

Comment: @TKJohn actually, starting with Java 9, `String` uses a `byte[]` array. But depending on the particular `CharSet`, `new String(byteArray, decoding)` may use a `CharBuffer` under the hood, additionally to the created result `String`. But for the optimized built-in charsets, using a `CharBuffer` may only pay off, if you reuse it.